# Why can't I use 'var' in constructor functions?

Tags: javascript

This works:

```
function Question(questionTitle, answer0, answer1) {

  this.questionTitle = questionTitle;
  this.answer0 = answer0;
  this.answer1 = answer1;

}
```

But this doesn't:

```
function Question(questionTitle, answer0, answer1) {

  var this.questionTitle = questionTitle;
  var this.answer0 = answer0;
  var this.answer1 = answer1;

}
```

It comes up with the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this". What's wrong with using `var`? Doesn't JavaScript interpret new variables being created even without adding the `var` keyword?

Tangent question: does it add variable names to the global namespace when `var` isn't used?

Comment: just do var questionTitle, not var this.questionTitle, although you will probably have conflicts since you have already a variable called questionTitle.

Comment: you can't define object properties with `var` keyword

Comment: `something.name = someValue` is setting a property of the object `something`. `var name = someValue` is declaring a local variable. Those two things are very different and use a different syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tangent question: does it add variable names to the global namespace
>   when var isn't used?

This appears to be at the root of your misunderstanding.  When you use this syntax:

```
function Question(questionTitle, answer0, answer1) {
  this.questionTitle = questionTitle;
  this.answer0 = answer0;
  this.answer1 = answer1;
}
```

Each one of those lines of code in that function adds or sets a property on the object pointed to by `this`.  As long as `this` does not point to the global object, but to some other object, then "NO", it does not add names to the global namespace.  It adds properties to the object pointed by `this`.  A line of code like:

```
  this.questionTitle = questionTitle;
```

instructs Javascript to take the object pointed to by `this`.   Set the property on that object named `questionTitle` to the value of the `questionTitle` variable.  If such a property does not already exist, then create it and give it this value.

So, if you use this function like this:

```
var q1 = new Question(...);
```

Then, those three lines of code in the constructor just add three properties to the `q1` object.  **They have no impact on the global namespace at all.**

This syntax is NOT creating new variables in the sense you are discussing.  It's creating new properties on an object.  And in Javascript, `var` is not used when assigning properties to an object.  You just assign the property with `object.property = value` syntax and if the property does not already exist, this will create it for you.

---

Your other syntax does not work simply because it's illegal syntax in Javascript.  The identifier that comes after `var` must follow a set of syntax rules and one of those rules is that it cannot contain a period so it's simply illegal syntax.

Even if the syntax for your second example was somehow allowed, it would be creating local variables only available within the constructor function scope and would not be creating properties on your object anyway.

Comment: This helped me understand my problem! So when we have `var q1 = new Question(...);`, does `this` refer to `q1`? And what's the difference between using properties and variables (`this.x` vs `var x`)? Don't they do the same thing?

Comment: @jazza_m8 `this` refers to the calling object, so adding a property to `this` will bind it to the calling object, whereas just using `var` only creates a variable that can't be used out of its scope.

Comment: @jazza_m8 - Yes, when executing `var q1 = new Question(...);`, inside the `Question` constructor function, `this` will point to the object that is returned and assigned to `q1`.  However, `this.x = "foo"` creates a property on that object pointed to by `this`.  `var x = "foo"` creates a local variable in the current function scope.  The two are not even close to the same thing. The local variable is accessible only inside the function scope and will exist as long as the function scope. The property is accessible for anyone who has a reference to the object and lasts as long as the object does.

Comment: So I just tested it out, and `var` is only accessible locally within the function like you both said. How does this relate to closures? Although I'm not familiar with them, I thought this would be a closure situation where the (constructor) function saves the state that it's created in, including variables.

Comment: @jazza_m8 - You can read about how to use local variables and methods defined within the constructor and the corresponding closure to create "private" instance variables here: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures.  Closures themselves are a much longer conversation which aren't going to be described in a few comments here.  There are lots of articles about them on the web so I'd suggest you do some reading there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do `var this.foo = 'bar';` because it doesn't make any syntactical sense.

- `var` declares a variable.
- `this` refers to the calling object within its direct scope.

For example, this:

```
function someObject(){
    // We are assigning `someObject` its own property `foo`.
    this.foo = 'bar';
}
```

is different from this:

```
function someObject(){
    // We are assigning some variable within the scope of this function named `foo`
    var foo = 'bar';
}
```

So hopefully you can see how doing this...

```
function someObject(){
    // Illegal
    var this.foo = 'bar';
}
```

... wouldn't work.